# Test location is ignored when test are run from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

I have problem with GPS location while running tests on iOS simulator from command line. I have app that requires location to run, so in my test scheme -  "MyProjectUITests" I have set Core Location and Test Location to some GPS coordinates. It works perfectly fine when tests are run from Xcode IDE (8.1 - 8B62) but if i run them from command line:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace \
    -scheme "MyProjectUITests" \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=10.1' \
    test
```

then app do not get location. I've noticed that in case of running from Xcode IDE simulator starts with "Debug > Location" set to "None" but when app/tests starts it is automatically switched to "Custom Location" so app could start without problem, but when tests are run from command line it stays set to "None" and all tests fail.

I am assuming that Xcode IDE executes that tests with some additional settings and I just need to add them to my script. So does anyone knows how exactly it runs tests or where/how I could check it?

Comment: Have you tried adding 'build' as a build action (immediately prior to test)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with "build" and "build-for-testing" but it does not help. I've also tried setting "-configuration" flag, but without any progress.